# How to configure JBoss EAP (6.4.x) for a combined HTTP/HTTPS reverse proxy?

Tags: jboss, reverse-proxy, jboss-eap-6

Our application runs in a JBoss EAP 6.4. Our development setup provides JBoss instance running in HTTP mode on port 8080 and a reverse proxy with both HTTP (port 9090) and HTTPS (port 9443) endpoints to help test different scenarios.

A problem arises when I try to use "current" URL by injecting the `UriInfo` into my request handlers. The scheme part of the URI inside is always dependent on the scheme attribute of the connector setting in the `standalone.xml` and not on the actual used scheme. So for example, if I call `https://localhost:9443` and `http://localhost:9090` when connector's scheme is set to `https`, both URLs are converted to HTTPS, i.e. `https://localhost:9443` but also `https://localhost:9090`. If I switch connector's scheme to `http`, both URLs change to HTTP. Needless to say, `X-Forwarded-Proto` is also ignored.

Is there a way to make JBoss behave more like most other application servers, i.e. without making any assumptions about used environment and especially reverse proxies and load balancers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RemoteIpValve** should do everything you need.

Source code from the JBossWeb 7.5.20 (EAP 6.4.20):
http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossweb/tags/JBOSSWEB_7_5_20_FINAL/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.java

Here's more readable documentation at the upstream Apache Tomcat 7.0 project website:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html

The minimum config in your case would be the following global valve configuration in the web subsystem:

```
<valve name="remoteip-valve" module="org.jboss.as.web" class-name="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve">
    <param param-name="protocolHeader" param-value="X-Forwarded-Proto"/>
</valve>
```

This would set the scheme based on the value of the X-Forwarded-Proto header.
For https it would also set the secure flag to true and port to 443.
Since you seem to require the HTTPS port to be set to 9443, you can do it via additional **httpsServerPort** parameter (and I think you'll also need to set the httpServerPort to 9090 as you mention above, because the RemoteIpValve would override it to 80 otherwise), e.g.

```
<valve name="remoteip-valve" module="org.jboss.as.web" class-name="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve">
    <param param-name="protocolHeader" param-value="X-Forwarded-Proto"/>
    <param param-name="httpServerPort" param-value="9090"/>
    <param param-name="httpsServerPort" param-value="9443"/>
</valve>
```

And you can do more with that valve if you need, just check the documentation for more details.

It's also briefly described for example here (RH login required): https://access.redhat.com/solutions/629863

BTW If you'd be able to use the AJP protocol (from the proxy to the app. server) instead, this wouldn't be needed as AJP is designed for these cases and all the required information should be transferred to the app. server pretty much transparently.

Comment: I'm marking the answer as correct, since `RemoteIpValve` is the right way, but I had to take a harder way: the `RemoteIpValve` included with EAP 6.4 is rather old and doesn't support `X-Forwarded-Port` (und thus resets any HTTP/HTTPS port to 80/443). I had to extract a `RemoteIpValve` from current Tomcat, put it into separate JAR and include it as a module in my EAP installation. But otherwise, `RemoteIpValve` is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, it's rather old code, mostly based on Tomcat 7.0. I had to do something similar with the SSLValve when experimenting with this some time ago.
EAP 7 doesn't use the Tomcat code and thus there are no such valves) and all this could be done via expression-filter on the undertow subsystem which are quite flexible.